# Elasticsearch AND condition with term query

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

This is my search filter query , 
I want to give "and" condition for terms.
Now I have given must inside the filter condition

```
'query' => [
    "filtered" => [
        "query" => [
            "match_all" => []
        ],
        "filter" => [
            "bool" => [
                "must" => [
                    "terms" => [
                        "num" => [
                            1,2,3
                        ]
                    ],
                    "terms" => [
                        "sample" => [
                            "a", "b"
                        ],
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'query' => [
            'multi_match' => [
                'query' => "Hello",
                'fields' => ['text'],
                'operator' => 'and'
            ],
        ]
    ]
],
```

but its not working. Any other solution for this?

Comment: what is the query searching for ? can you explain ?

Comment: select * from table where text="%Hello%" and num in(1,2,3) and sample in("a","b")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose your `terms` filters in one more array, otherwise your `bool/must` becomes an associative array and that's not what you want (i.e. one of the `terms` filter gets discarded).

```
'query' => [
    "filtered" => [
        "query" => [
            "match_all" => []
        ],
        "filter" => [
            "bool" => [
                "must" => [
                   [                     <---
                      "terms" => [
                         "num" => [
                            1,2,3
                         ]
                      ]
                   ],                    <---
                   [                     <---
                      "terms" => [
                        "sample" => [
                            "a", "b"
                        ],
                      ]
                   ]                     <---
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'query' => [
            'multi_match' => [
                'query' => "Hello",
                'fields' => ['text'],
                'operator' => 'and'
            ],
        ]
    ]
],
```

Answer (score 1):

try this out, when you want to add 'and' condtion, just add that part in the bool,must.

```
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"terms":{"num":[1,2,3]}},{"terms":{"sample":["a","b"]}},{"match":{"text":"hello"}}]}},"from":0,"size":10}
```